# Array using double

Tags: java, double

This is the code that I made.... for the array code

```
public class main
{
  public static int arraySum(int[] arr)
  {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      result += arr[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
  public static int arraySumBetter(int [] a)
  {
    int result = 0;
    for (int value : a)
    {
      result += value;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    double[] a ={0,2,3,1,0.56};
    System.out.format("%.1f", (double) arraySumBetter(a));
  }
}
```

when I run it it prints an error out:

> typed.java:25: error: incompatible types: double[] cannot be
>   converted to int[]
>       System.out.format("%.1f", (double) arraySumBetter(a));
>
> Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with
>   -Xdiags:verbose to get full output1 error

I thought to add decimal numbers using double would be work but it didn't work..
Is there any way to fix this? I would appreciate any tips... thanks...

Comment: My english is not that good so if you guys write details i would be appreciated

Comment: change your arraySumBetter method's parameter type to double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not cast from a type to a whole different non related type. With that said `double != int`. Instead of casting here

```
   System.out.format("%.1f", (double) arraySumBetter(a));
                               ^ remove
```

You could change your methods to accept a `double[]` array as parameter like this

```
public static double arraySumBetter(double[] a)
  {
    double result = 0;
    for (double value : a)
    {
      result += value;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Note that I changed your primitive type from `int` to `double` or else you would lose the decimal points.

Comment: @W.J What did you do?

Comment: @W.J I changed the return type of `arraySumBetter` to `double` I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 1):

use double as IN and OUT in your function.. see my comments

```
  public static int arraySum(int[] arr)
  {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      result += arr[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
  public static double arraySumBetter(double [] a) //<<<<<<<<<<<< IN: double, OUT: also double, else the decimals are lost 
  {
    double result = 0; //<<<<<<<<<< here use double, else you loose decimals
    for (double value : a) //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< value is double, because a is double[]
    {
      result += value;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    double[] a ={0,2,3,1,0.56};
    System.out.format("%.1f", (double) arraySumBetter(a));
  }
```

Comment: I was thinking of printing out 2 or 3 digits number like 5.55 than how do i do that?

Comment: "%.2f" instead of "%.1f" -> 2 digits